# Finding max. and min. daylight duration at a given latitude.

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, curves, geodesy

Here's my question: 
Compute the maximum & minimum daylight duration at the latitude of
Phila. PA. (39.9500◦N) in hours and minutes. Approximating to the
nearest minute.

What would be the best way to begin this? Just to be clear, Im not looking for the solution just a starting off point, any advice would be appreciated.

[image: Image of work]

Here's what I managed so far, from what I read online, it seems wrong. Does this maybe require spherical trig. instead?

Comment: It's almost as if you've copied your homework onto my screen and then asked me to do it for you.

Comment: Not my intention. Sorry if it seems like that. Id just like to get some advice on how to start this. Im not familiar with questions like this

Comment: In any case, please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22), such as showing your own work or pointing out what is specifically causing you trouble. Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the edits!

Comment: bear in mind, various online sources might not give you the theoretical day length ("theoretical" here meaning consistent with your assumptions), but rather the actual one, which is not quite the same for several reasons, such as Earth's orbit is not really a circle, but perhaps most importantly, the Sun is not really a point (in fact the effect of that is much more substantial than the Earth's and its orbit's sizes)

Comment: @NickPavlov As the ratio (Earth radius)/(Sun distance) is around $10^{-8}$ I think that considering the Sun a point, instead of having parallel light rays, could give an error of about $0.1$ seconds, well below the accuracy required here (1 minute).

Comment: @Aretino If that were true, a sunset would not take several minutes. It's the Sun's radius that matters, not the Earth's, which is exactly what I pointed out. Considering it as a point, you find the time from the moment its center rises above the horizon, to the moment its center sets. I believe when sunrise and sunset times are given, they refer to the top/bottom edges (i.e. first/last light). If it was a point, you could consider light rays parallel. As it is actually quite big, they are not, and the difference can be on the order of a few minutes (at high latitudes even more)

Comment: @NickPavlov What you say is absolutely correct, I was only pointing out that the difference between a pointlike Sun (as required in the question) and a situation where light rays from the Sun are parallel (as in my answer) is negligible.

Comment: @Aretino Indeed it is, parallel rays = point Sun, and my original comment was not at all directed to your take on it. I was merely suggesting to the OP that with this assumption, a precision of 1 minute is unrealistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

The red circle (lateral view) in figure below is the parallel of Philadelphia. To answer your question you must compute what fraction of it is exposed to sunlight in the two cases.

[image]

EDIT

Here's a diagram that could help you, representing the red circle in the minimum daylight case. $OH$ and $OP$ can be computed from the previous figure, and from them you can get $\alpha$. Daylight duration (in hours) is then $\displaystyle24{\alpha\over180°}$.

[image]